# Where can I find Shimano jockey wheels?

Tags: shimano

I have a Shimano RD-M510 rear derailleur that needs both jockey wheels replaced.  Were can I find them for this older unit?
Jerry

Comment: I can't see why generic 11T jockey wheels wouldn't work. Don't forget to loctite the threads when rebuilding the cage.

Answer (score 1):

The compatible part is SHIMANO RD 5700 and the part number is 5XH9812. The set come as a pair and is available at a number of places such as [Chain Reaction Cycles](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/nz/en/shimano-jockey-wheels-mtb/rp-prod885) and [Wiggle](http://www.wiggle.com/shimano-rd-5700-tension-guide-pulley-set/).

The only thing to ensure if using generics is that they are the right chain size.

Answer (score 1):

Tacx manufactures some great jockey wheels which are compatible with Shimano/Sram/Campagnolo products. Search for "Tacx Jockey Wheels" in your favourite online bike shop.

They come with cartridge bearings which work great before you use them in muddy conditions (MTB, CX). After these heavy conditions I have found then to lock up.

In case of a road bike, I would totally reccomend them, the difference when spinngin pedals backwards is noticable.

Answer (score 0):

Most on line retailers Chainreaction cycles, BlueSky cycles, Excel Sports carry them. Your LBS should also be able to get them if they don't stock them. They may be called derailleur pulleys or jockey wheels. You want to measure the wheel width and tooth count if you are using something other than an exact replacement from Shimano. The top and bottom wheels are generally not interchangeable so make sure you order the correct ones if they are available as separate pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Shimano provides the following parts list for the RD-M510 (http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/RD/EV-RD-M510-1896_v1_m56577569830609142.pdf):

Y-5UN 98060 Guide Pulley

Y-5UN 98070 Tension Pulley

You can take this sheet to your LBS and get them to order it for you.